# Backup/Restore Android

Tags: rooting, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I perform a full pre-rooting backup of an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/how-do-i-perform-a-full-pre-rooting-backup-of-an-android-phone)

I am considering rooting my Motorola Droid, and I am wondering if it is possible to revert back to the exact state that my phone is in right now (ie unrooted, with all my apps, settings, etc).

I know I can backup all the files on my SD card (in fact I have that job running right now).  But how can I backup/restore the phone's internal memory?

Is this what SPRecovery does?  All of the 'how-to-root-your-phone' tutorials say that you start by installing SPRecovery, but I can't find any details on what, exactly, SPRecovery does, and how to use it.  I suspect it does more than what is necessary to load a rooted ROM, but I just can't find any details.

Answer (score 6):

Could you use [Nandroid](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=459830) to do this? I understand that this creates a full image of your phone for restore.

Comment: Does it require rooting the phone? I've galaxy I5801

Comment: @Ismail In most cases, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The Marketplace has a few different free and pay apps that do backup. They can backup apps and the data stored with the apps as well as other things on your phone like your call log.

Backup on Android has never been too big a deal because most of what is really important on a phone (contacts, email) are stored in Google's cloud.

Once you root your phone you won't want to go back anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Note that you do not need to backup Contacts & Emails etc. They are automatically backed up in your google account.

The state of your apps (i.e. the purchases you have made) is also backed up to your google account. So if you move to a different android phone, you can install them again without having to pay for them again.

For photos, I have been very happy with [**Lookout for Android**](https://www.mylookout.com/). Important features include:

- Data Backup (I use only photo backup)
- Anti Virus (which I never use)
- Remote Locator (in case your phone gets stolen/lost)