# Root Nexus One without wiping?

Tags: rooting, nexus-one, backup

I have a Nexus One running Gingerbread (2.3.6), completely stock and unrooted. I would like to root my phone, and try installing ROMs like Cyanogen. However, as far as I know, the official way to do so, `fastboot oem unlock`, will wipe my phone, causing me to lose all of my data.

Is there any good way for me to root my phone without wiping, so that I can use something like Titanium Backup to back up all of my data before I unlock my bootloader and thus wipe my data?

If not, is there any good, automated way, to back up as much data as possible without root, and give me some indication of what could not be backed up? I don't want to have to go through every application and figure out if it has some way of exporting its data.

Answer (score 6):

[This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=736271) provides a method for rooting without unlocking, though I don't know if it will still work for 2.3.6.  Worth a shot.  If I doesn't I think you'd need to downgrade your firmware to avoid unlocking, which would wipe your data anyways.

As for backing up without root, see [How can data on an unrooted phone be backed up?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12470/how-can-data-on-an-unrooted-phone-be-backed-up)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to flawlessly root Nexus One with stock 2.3.6 with [DooMLoRD's Easy Rooting Toolkit [v4.0](zergRush Exploit)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=18805532&postcount=1).

This also installed Busybox and Superuser app.

No bootloader unlock or wipe was performed and no user data or apps were lost.

Some useful info can be also obtained here:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/HTC_Nexus_One/Flashing_Guide

Comment: Thanks! I'd forgotten I'd even asked this question, and have even moved on to a Nexus 4, but good to know anyhow, maybe I'll play around with my N1 again at some point.