# Can I make a full backup of my phone with Odin and without root?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, backup, odin, heimdall

As a follow up to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/how-do-i-perform-a-full-pre-rooting-backup-of-an-android-phone), is it possible to use Odin (or Heimdall) to save a complete image of my phone without root?

Odin already allows me to completely overwrite pretty much everything on my phone without root.  Can Odin be used to *read* the entire contents of the phone over USB without root?  Ideally, I'd expect the output of such a read to be something I can write in the future with Odin.

While this question is somewhat general, I'm guessing that by asking about Odin and Heimdall I'm limiting it to Samsung phones (though I may be wrong).

Comment: Better to do Nandroid backup...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Odin is Samsung-only, you're right.  (And as far as I know it isn't for all Samsung phones either, though I could be wrong on that.)  Since Heimdall is, as far as I know, just an unofficial port of Odin I would assume it's the same, but I've never used it.

Odin3 has a "Dump" function that I had never used.  It seems to be disabled in v1.8x and v1.7, but not in v1.52.

I just tried it in v1.52 and it didn't work.  You hit the **Dump** checkmark under `Option`, select an output file via the **Dump** button under `File [Dump]`, then hit **Start**.  Odin will say "OneNAND Dump Start" or similar as it backs up the device.  It only backed up 1 KB of something before halting, though.  Odin just sat there without giving an error message.

You might have different results with a different device (I have a Vibrant).  I'm also wondering whether my Ext4 lagfix might be affecting this.  Perhaps later I'll flash to stock 2.1 and try again.  **Edit:** No change on stock 2.1 JFD.

Comment: Did you ever try this after flashing to stock?

Comment: @NathanFellman I tried just now, thanks for reminding me.  The behavior was the same.

Comment: Heimdall (open-source alternative to ODIN) also allows to dump data from the Phone, maybe that is something you're looking for: https://github.com/Benjamin-Dobell/Heimdall/blob/v1.3.2/heimdall/source/Interface.cpp (See Action "Dump")

Answer (score -1):

Check the [Nandroid Backup](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/what-is-a-nandroid-backup-and-how-exactly-does-it-work/) application
[image: nandroid app img]

Comment: Doesn't this require root?