# Can I use ODIN to just back up my phone's data?

Tags: rom-flashing, odin

The goal here is to be able to quickly get all my settings and apps back when moving from ROM to ROM, but do so without overwriting the kernel, themes, etc., in the new ROM.  I know I can use Titanium Backup, but ODIN would definitely be faster (and half the time with my Droid Charge, it's what I'm using to flash the new ROM anyway).

Answer (score 4):

No, Odin is just for flashing.  The Dump command doesn't seem to work, at least not as of Odin3 v1.85; see [Can I make a full backup of my phone with Odin and without root?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13623/can-i-make-a-full-backup-of-my-phone-with-odin-and-without-root/13632#13632)