# How can I backup all of my data to a PC without rooting?

Tags: backup, htc-incredible-s

I am an ex-Nokia user and used to backup the data with their PC Suite which is great and can backup everything easily and is a free application.

How do I do the same with HTC Incredible S?

[ *I do not plan to get rooted.* ]

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/how-do-i-perform-a-full-pre-rooting-backup-of-an-android-phone and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can back up your sd card to a PC by mounting it from the PC or over the network with a number of different syncing tools. This will not backup each application's state unless they specifically have exported configuration to the sd card. This *will* include all your pictures.

You cannot back up application state (to a PC) without root. See the other "possible duplicates" and "related" questions for how and why this is.

There is supposedly a backup API built into android ([developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html)) but I have yet to see that actually be used, or see any reports by others of it working.