# How to Backup when Samsung G S3 not booting stuck at Samsung logo?

Tags: backup, samsung, boot

How to Backup when Samsung Galaxy S3 not booting stuck at Samsung text logo?

1. I can boot in the "Android System Recovery" Mode using "Volume Up"+"Home"+"Power".
2. I don't have ADB USB Debug set up.

   - When using ADB it can get the serial number:

   > adb devices -l
   >
   > List of devices attached
   >
   > 881aa70c       recovery

   - When using ADB pull to get all SDCard (the built-in 16G memory) - It cannot see any file on /sdcard/

   > adb pull /sdcard/ C:\U_adt
   >
   > pull: building file list...
   >
   > 0 files pulled. 0 files skipped.

   - When using ADB to pull the /sys/block/ where is the mmcblk0 which is mounted at boot as /SDCard/ it says skipping special file

   > adb pull /sys/block/ C:\U_adt
   >
   > pull: building file list...
   >
   > skipping special file 'ram0'
   >
   > skipping special file 'ram15'
   >
   > skipping special file 'loop0'
   >
   > skipping special file 'loop7'
   >
   > skipping special file 'mmcblk0'
   >
   > skipping special file 'mmcblk0boot1'
   >
   > skipping special file 'mmcblk0boot0'
   >
   > 0 files pulled. 0 files skipped.

   - When using ADB backup it says to confirm on the screen, but the phone can not boot to normal where may be the confirmation, and in "Recovery" there is no confirmation message.

   > adb backup -shared
   >
   > Now unlock your device and confirm the backup operation.

I want to backup the DCIM/Camera and other personal data.

How can the backup of pictures on internal memory /sdcard/ can be done?

I read here [How do I perform a full pre-rooting backup of an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/how-do-i-perform-a-full-pre-rooting-backup-of-an-android-phone?lq=1) that FACTORY RESET does not wipe the data from /sdcard/ internal memory.

But on my S3 in Android System Recovery the option is named "WIPE DATA/FACTORY RESET".

Will the option "WIPE DATA/FACTORY RESET" wipe /sdcard/ partition or not?

Comment: Can S3 be rooted when stuck on boot? How? Root in order to run Titanium Backup (which only backs up apps and their data) or root in order to flash ClockWork Recovery which lets you perform a Nandroid backup (full image backup of the entire device).

Comment: /sdcard (internal memory) is not wiped in a factory reset, only the system partitions. - Does this mean I can do a factory reset without any camera pictures loss?

Comment: That is true, @George.  If you do a factory reset, /sdcard and /sdcard-ext will not be wiped.  Why isn't your phone booting?  We should get to the root of that problem first.

Answer (score 2):

I used my S3 in "Android System Recovery"

The option "WIPE DATA/FACTORY RESET" seems to npt wipe /sdcard/ partition.

in my case it resolved the isue, now the phone is not stuck, and all the apps that were deleted are re-installed from the cloud by Android because I had backup them on the cloud.

Just as a side note, before  I used the above option to get rid of boot stuck on samasung logo, I couldn't use ODIN to install an original firmware downloaded from here:
http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/3/?download=14509

Answer (score 0):

from recovery

```
`./adb pull /dev/block/mmcblk0 mmcblk0.img`
```

If your recovery won't support that you can use download mode (power  +volume up) to replace your recovery with [TWRP](https://twrp.me/Devices/) which is what I used adb pull on (to recover some deleted files).

Comment: Have you verified that your answer works on stock Android recovery? They often run adb daemon in a very restrictive mode. Also, your answer ended up in VLQ queue.

Comment: good point @Firelord , answer updated.