# How can I make a full, restorable image of my pre-root Android hard drive, as in Clonezilla?

Tags: rooting, clockworkmod-recovery, restore, nandroid

In Clonezilla, one boots OS-1 (Clonezilla) on Drive-1 (USB stick) in order to make a full, restorable image of Drive-2 (which may contain OS-2) on Drive-3 (the backup drive). One does not need any permissions or "root" on Drive-2 or OS-2 in order to make this copy. In fact, one could perform this procedure on any drive at all, including your drives, without knowing any of the relevant passwords!

- **Question #1:** How can I use free software on OS-1 (Linux, Windows, etc.) to make a full, restorable image of Drive-2 (*brand new, untouched Android phone*), including ROM, bootloader(s), and any other sections, partitions, etc.?

  If you believe the answer is, "You can't," then..
- **Question #2:** After I have rooted, how can I restore Drive-2' (*the rooted and thus altered Android phone*) to its original state, Drive-2 (*brand new, untouched Android phone*)?

  If you believe the answer is, "You can't," then..
- **Question #3:** Why should I not worry about this?

It seems odd that one must alter Drive-2 (rooting process) in order to make a copy of Drive-2', but it seems like ClockworkMod's NANDroid images (and others) do exactly this by requiring root. Perhaps I am simply confused.

Answer (score 0):

1. In general, you need to root the device to make a full backup. After you've rooted the device, use nandroid (which it seems you already know about). You can make a backup that doesn't include the OS by following one of the answers to [How do I perform a full pre-rooting backup of an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/how-do-i-perform-a-full-pre-rooting-backup-of-an-android-phone)
2. By flashing the stock ROM and recovery for your device, and wiping the userdata partition. See [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device) to find the stock ROM for your phone.
3. Because if you've broken the OS, recovery, and bootloader on your device sufficiently that you can't just flash a ROM image the usual way, there's no way you'd be able to restore any kind of backup image.