# What happens with configurations and app data, practically, if I mod my device with custom firmware?

Tags: cyanogenmod, backup, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to backup an Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device)

If I want to install a  modified firmware like [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/), it seems like I should wipe the phone clean both [before](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8966/do-i-need-to-revert-to-stock-firmware-and-or-wipe-data-before-installing-a-custom) and [after](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=15626837&postcount=2) the operation.

But what will happen to all of my

- Android configurations (known Wi-Fi networks, bluetooth pairings, etc)
- installed apps
- app data
- app configurations?

Is there a simple way to make a backup of all of that and then restore them after the wipe on the brand new OS?

What about stuff on SD card? Should I wipe the SD card clean too? What about the apps that are installed there?

*(I've tried to look for [other](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5667/how-do-i-perform-a-full-pre-rooting-backup-of-an-android-phone) [backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-to-backup-an-android-device) [related](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/650/backup-restore-android) [questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7168/what-is-the-right-way-to-backup-my-whole-phone), but they have to do with restoring the device to the exact same state - which of course would be the usual case when restoring backups.)*

Comment: You should read the answers to those questions, partial backups and restores are entirely covered.