# Will deleted apps be restored when I reset factory data?

Tags: applications, data-recovery, restore

I need to reset my phone to get it back to what it was like when I first bought it. If I reset it to factory settings, will the apps I've deleted be restored as well?
If not how do I find and restore those apps?

Comment: These deleted apps: did you delete them from the system partition or the userdata partition?

Answer (score -1):

Inbuilt apps that you deleted/disabled will be restored. Any apps that you installed from Google Play and weren't pre-installed on your phone wont't be restored.

You will have to redownload those apps again which you want to use again. Also give [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/650/backup-restore-android?lq=1) a read and the linked question inside.

Comment: Deleted system apps will not return on factory reset, only when the ROM is reflashed.